# Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory -- but file exists

Tags: python

I am currently teaching myself Python using the Head First Python series (I am using the first edition). The book provides sample code to run a website on my local machine with a link to file within the `webapp` directory. The current file structure looks like this:

```
webapp
  |
  cgi-bin
     |
    athletelist.py
    athletemodel.py
    generate_list.py
    generate_timing_data.py
    yate.py
  data
  images
  templates
  coach.css
  index.html
  simple_httpd.py
```

Here's a screenshot of files within `/webapp/cgi-bin/`
[Screenshot of cgi-bin directory after 'ls -' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j84bQ.png)

I've made the file, `generate_list.py` an executable using `chmod +x` command per instructions provided in the book. My issue occurs when I try to click a link in the index.html file `<a href='./cgi-bin/generate_list.py'>timing data </a>` as Python is not able to find the file (I've attached an image of the error in my terminal).
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhTxd.png]

I am on MacOS Ventura using python version 3.11.3. If helpful, I installed python via homebrew and use pyenv to swap between versions.

I've tried changing the pathing from relative to absolute, but the same error persists. At the top of the `generate_list.py` file, I have the following line of code added (per instruction in Head First Python) `#! /usr/local/bin/python3`. I've tried switching this to `#! /Users/user-name/.pyenv/versions.3.11.3/bin/python` but am still not able to locate the file.

[For clarity, I've attached a screenshot from my editor. You can see the file in question under cgi-bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGDs9.png)

Comment: Can you include the output you get when you run `ls -l /Users/Connor/Desktop/webapp/cgi-bin/` in a terminal? By far the simplest explanation is that the file is not actually there. For example, in your tree diagram you refer to `cig-bin`, when it should be `cgi-bin`.

Comment: tree shows `cig-bin`,  error shows `cgi-bin`?

Comment: Hi @phihag & @richard, thank you both for your response. The `cig-bin` is a typo on my end; apologies for that. I've edited my original post to include a screenshot from the `ls -l` command you asked for @phihag

Comment: How are you running the webserver? Maybe the user that runs the process doesn't have permission to view files in those directories

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 I am using the `HTTPServer` & `CGIHTTPRequestHandler` modules from Python. Here's my code:

``` 
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
port = 8080

httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
print('Starting simple_httpd on port: ' + str(httpd.server_port))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add information, don't use comments. Thanks.

Comment: @Clu-Codes In the screenshot, you cropped off the original command. Note that the terminal shows `~/desktop/w/cgi-bin/`. Note the upper-case vs lower-case `D/d` in desktop, and `webapp` being shortened to `w` (although the latter might be a shortened display by the shell).

Comment: @phihag Sorry about that. I appreciate your patience here, too. I've edited the post to include better screenshots. I do not think the capitalization `D/d` matters here; I've tested both with no success. :(